# Triggering responsive behavior when dynamically resizing amCharts 4 chart

Tags: javascript, charts, responsive, amcharts, amcharts4

The most recent version of amCharts (I'm using v4.7.8) includes a couple of mechanisms to allow for responsive chart designs.  I'm trying to take advantage of the `chart.responsive.rules` feature, which allows for different chart property values based on the size of the chart (and/or inner chart elements).

At the same time, we've implemented a "zoom" feature on all of our charts.  Each chart is wrapped in a "zoomable" container element, and the charts are styled to be 95% of the container width.  When the "zoom" icon-button is clicked, the container is set to `position: fixed; top: 3rem; right: 3rem; bottom: 3rem; left: 3rem;`, mostly filling the screen.

The problem is that the chart just... doesn't seem to notice this.  If I *create* the chart at the zoomed size, it uses the correct ruleset, but if I create the chart at a smaller size, then resize it to be large, it continues to use the "small" ruleset.  I've tried calling `chart.appear`, `chart.invalidate`, and `chart.deepInvalidate` after resizing, but the result is always the same: the chart renders with whatever ruleset it was originally initialized with.

The one thing that makes me think that at least SOMETHING is happening (though mis-timed) is the fact that when I zoom in (so the chart is fullscreen) and then use the horizontal scrollbar, the scrollbar moves faster than my mouse cursor - almost as if it thinks it's smaller than it is. That holds up with my initial impressions. However, once I resize the chart BACK to being small, the scrollbar moves *slower* than my mouse cursor, as if it thinks the chart is BIGGER than it is.

This whole thing is all done with multiple LitElement web components, so it's difficult to provide a fiddle/codepen example, but if necessary I can mock up an example that should at least demonstrate the problem. I'm not sure if that would be necessary, as I suspect someone who knows what they're talking about would know the answer to this offhand, but if you think it'll help, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Edit: I've found a workaround, but it's hardly ideal. I found that if I completely dispose of the existing chart on zoom in/out and completely recreate it at the new size, then it behaves the way I want, but it is SERIOUSLY processor intensive to recreate some of these charts.  I'd still very much prefer to find a solution that can take advantage of the current chart and just recalculate its layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the answer is that amCharts 4 does not support the actual properties I'm trying to change via the responsive rules. The properties in question are `groupData` and `groupCount`.  Support tells me that the logic surrounding those features was considered too complex to support dynamic updates.  I asked them to please reconsider that decision. We shall see if they do.

What I've done in the meantime to solve my problem is to create two charts, one configured for the larger size and one for the smaller size, and I just swap out which one is displayed when zooming in/out.

Answer (score 0):

try using setTimeout(()=>{chart.responsive.enabled = false;chart.responsive.enabled = true; }) after resize

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help.  And why in a setTimeout?